# Registration system doesn't create me a .txt file that i need. Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have followed this tutorial on how to make a GUI registration and login system: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xt6SqWuMSA8

Everything goes perfect except the fact that in my case, the program doesn't create a file with username and password like in his video.

In my case it only makes a blank .txt file.

You can watch what I mean in the video at minute: 18:45.

This is how it looks after I press "Inregistrare":

[image]

It should make a second .txt file named: "`asds.txt`"

I have followed his tutorial and it works, except the fact with that file that contains username and password. I don't know what else to try, so I decided to ask you.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import sys


    def inregistrare_utilizator():
    usernameInfo = utilizator.get()
    passwordInfo = parola.get()

    file = open(usernameInfo + ".txt", "w")
    file.write(usernameInfo + "\n")
    file.write(passwordInfo)
    file.close()

    utilizatorEntry.delete(0, END)
    parolaEntry.delete(0, END)

    labe1 = Label(windows4, text="succes").pack()


    def register():
    global windows4
    windows4 = Tk()
    windows4.title("EasyQuizy v1.0 - Inregistrare")
    windows4.geometry("400x200+180+350")
    windows4.resizable(False, False)

    label1 = Label(windows4, text="Completeaza campurile de mai jos pentru inregistrare.")
    label1.pack()
    label2 = Label(windows4, text="Tot ce este notat cu * este obligatoriu!")
    label2.pack()
    label5 = Label(windows4, text="")
    label5.pack()
    label3 = Label(windows4, text="Username* ")
    label3.place(x=60, y=80)
    label4 = Label(windows4, text="Parola* ")
    label4.place(x=60, y=110)
    inregistrareButon = Button(windows4, text="Inregistrare", command=inregistrare_utilizator)
    inregistrareButon.pack()
    inregistrareButon.place(x=180, y=150)

    global utilizator
    global parola
    global utilizatorEntry
    global parolaEntry

    utilizator = StringVar()
    parola = StringVar()

    utilizatorEntry = Entry(windows4, textvariable=utilizator, width=20)
    utilizatorEntry.pack()
    utilizatorEntry.place(x=150, y=80)
    parolaEntry = Entry(windows4, textvariable=parola, width=20)
    parolaEntry.pack()
    parolaEntry.place(x=150, y=110)

    windows4.mainloop()

    def succes():
    global windows2
    windows2 = Tk()
    windows2.overrideredirect(1)
    windows2.geometry("300x50+760+450")
    windows2.title("EasyQuizy v1.0")
    windows2.resizable(False, False)
    windows2.after(2000, lambda: windows2.destroy())
    text = Label(windows2, width=300, height=25, text="Succes!", borderwidth=4, relief=RIDGE, fg="#4bf04b",
                 bg="#F9F8F9", font="arial 22 bold underline", command=windows1.destroy()).pack(anchor=CENTER)
    text2 = Label(windows2, command=inceput())
    text2.pack()

    windows2.mainloop()


    def drepturi_autor():
    global frame
    frame = Frame(windows3, highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=2, width=(390),
                  height=(150), bg="#afd5c1")
    frame.place(x=105, y=90)
    label1 = Label(frame, width=(26),
                   text="EasyQuizy este o aplicatieee e\ncreata de mine pentru tine.\nTest test test teste test\nTest test test teste test\nTest test test teste test",
                   bg="#82ac96", fg="#f2f2f2", font="arial 14 bold italic")
    label1.pack(side=LEFT)
    label1.place(x=7, y=5)
    frame.after(2000, frame.destroy)


    def inceput():
    global windows3
    windows3 = Tk()
    windows3.title("EasyQuizy v1.0")
    windows3.geometry("600x600+600+200")
    windows3.resizable(False, False)
    windows3.configure(bg="#472025")

    headerFrame = Frame(windows3, width=("100"), height=("0")).pack(side=TOP)
    frameLeft = Frame(windows3, width="100", height="600", bg="#7b8781")
    frameLeft.place(x=0, y=0)
    frameRight = Frame(windows3, width="100", height="600", bg="#7b8781")
    frameRight.place(x=500, y=0)
    header = Label(headerFrame, width=("100"), height=("3"), bg="#9d7448", fg="#d9ab33", borderwidth=1, relief="solid",
                   font="Helvetica 14 bold italic", text=("Bine ai venit, " + str(numeUtilizator.get()) + '!'))
    header.pack()

    # BUTOANE PE PARTEA STANGA!
    butonRights = Button(frameLeft, width=("9"), height=("2"), text="Drepturi de \nautor", bg="#6ab891", fg="#131313",
                         font="arial 8 bold", borderwidth=4, relief="raised", command=drepturi_autor)
    butonRights.place(x=7, y=100)
    ############################################################
    butonInfo = Button(frameLeft, width=("9"), height=("2"), text="Imbunatatiri", bg="#6ab891", fg="#131313",
                       font="arial 8 bold", borderwidth=4, relief="raised")
    butonInfo.place(x=7, y=180)

    butonExit = Button(frameRight, width=6, height=2, text="Exit", bg="#c51418", fg="#131313",
                       font="arial 10 bold underline", borderwidth=4, relief=RAISED, command=sys.exit)
    butonExit.place(x=15, y=540)
    #############################################################477998
    butonRegister = Button(headerFrame, width=10, height=2, bg="#477998", fg="#291f1e", text="Inregistrare",
                           font="arial 8 bold", borderwidth=4, relief="raised", command=register)
    butonRegister.place(x=28, y=15)
    ############################################################
    butonLogin = Button(headerFrame, width=11, bg="#c4d6b0", fg="#291f1e", height=2, text="Autentificare",
                        font="arial 8 bold", borderwidth=4, relief="raised")
    butonLogin.place(x=480, y=15)

    windows3.mainloop()

global windows1
windows1 = Tk()
windows1.title("EasyQuizy v1.0")
windows1.geometry("1280x720+300+160")
windows1.resizable(False, False)

header = Label(windows1, text="Bun venit la EasyQuizy, un joc de inteligenţă şi strategie!", bg="#878067",
               fg="#A1BBCD", font=("arial 16 bold"), width=("200"), height=("3"))
header.pack()

# Introducere nume
numePreluareText = Label(windows1, text="Numele tău: ", font="arial 12", fg="black")
numePreluareText.pack(anchor=CENTER)
doar_12_caractere = Label(windows1, width="24", text="ATENŢIE! Maxim 12 caractere!", font="arial 10 italic",
                          fg="red", bg="#b6b0b0")
doar_12_caractere.place(x=517, y=200)

global numeUtilizator
numeUtilizator = StringVar()

EntryNume = Entry(windows1, textvariable=numeUtilizator, font="arial 12", bg="#c8c6bd")
EntryNume.pack(anchor=CENTER)

# FUNCTIE!!!!
    def length(numeUtilizator):
        if len(numeUtilizator.get()) > 12:
            numeUtilizator.set(numeUtilizator.get()[-1])

# FUNCTIE!!!!

numeUtilizator.trace("w", lambda *args: length(numeUtilizator))

butonOk = Button(windows1, width="3", height="1", text="OK", font="arial 8 bold", bg="#70e5ee", command=succes)
butonOk.pack(anchor=CENTER)

windows1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place. Please fix it first

Comment: I have edited your question. I think it works. You should try it again with the code above.

Comment: Works for me as expected.

Comment: I tried @Miraj50's edited version. If i put it in another python file, it works. 
If i replace it with my whole code, it doesn't work.. Should i put all my code above?

Comment: You should replace it with an [mcve].